# NullPointerException after simple clojure program

Tags: clojure

I am working on learning clojure, and have run into a NullPointerException that seems to have nothing to do with my code.  The program runs to completion before producing the error.  The code:

```
; solves the collatz conjecture

; return one step in the sequence
(defn collatz-step [n] 
  (if (= (rem n 2) 0)
    (/ n 2)
    (+ 1 (* 3 n))))

; recurse over all numbers
(defn collatz [n] 
  (if (= n 1)
    (println "All done!")
    ((println (format "N = %d" n)) 
     (collatz (collatz-step n)))))

; get input and run it
(println "Enter a positive number:")
(collatz (read-string (read-line)))
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when this line runs:

```
((println (format "N = %d" n)) 
 (collatz (collatz-step n)))
```

the println and colatz will finish leving the form like this:

```
 (return-value-of-println return-value-of-collatz)
```

println returns nil yielding:

```
 (nil return-value-of-collatz)
```

which is a function call to the function nil resulting in an NPE

take out the extra ()

---

Clojure does not have tail call elimination, so changing your recursive call to `collatz` to `recur` will keep it from blowing the stack on large values of n

Comment: Oh man, thank you so much.  That makes total sense.  I thought that to group multiple statements, I had to list them in parenthesis.  Now I learned about the (do ) form which solves that problem.

I was banging my head over this for so long, thanks again!

Comment: functions add the do automatically, so in this case you dont need it. The last form in a function is the return value